# Python: Separate list into variables

Tags: python

How can I turn

```
def square_error(f1,f2, u1,v1,sigu1,sigv1,rho1, u2,v2,sigu2,sigv2,rho2, u3,v3,sigu3,sigv3,rho3):
```

into:

```
def square_error(x):
#     x = [0.2,0.5,
#           1,1,1,1,0.3,
#           1,1,1,1,0.3,
#           1,1,1,1,0.3],
    f1,f2, u1,v1,sigu1,sigv1,rho1, u2,v2,sigu2,sigv2,rho2, u3,v3,sigu3,sigv3,rho3 = x
```

The `scipy.minimize` function only allow 1 argument for the target function, so I need to turn the variables into a single argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\*args and \*\*kwargs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Comment: `np.array(x)`?  I'm not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Alexander, I've update my question, could you see it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that, but you will have to the `*` syntax which will [unpack the array](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) into the parameters of the function.

For example:

```
def square_error( x,y,z ):
    print x,y,z

arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
square_error( *arr )
```

will unpack the values `1,2,3` into the parameters `x,y,z`

---

Or if you wanted to unpck the values into variables within the function, use [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

```
def square_error( arr ):
    x,y,z = arr
    print x,y,z

arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
square_error( arr )
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I may not be cleaer enough. I need to turn `def square_error(x,y,z):` into `def square_error(x):`, and within the function, unpack the `x` into `x,y,z`. How can I do that? The `scipy.minimize` function seems only allow for `1 argument`.

Comment: Ah in that case, you don't need to do anything special, I've edited my answer.